# CSS/Ruby beginner - why are two buttons next to each other different sizes?

Tags: html, css, ruby

My search and login buttons beside each other are different sizes. I'm guessing it's because the search button is within a submit_tag argument and login is not? If that's the answer, my question is how would I get the login button to conform? It seems to have double the padding of the search button and extends the top and bottom of the navbar. If I remove "btn" from "btn btn-search" at least the navbar dimensions are constrained, but the button extands all the way to the top and bottom. Thanks in advance.

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbarCollapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div><!--end navbar-header-->


    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbarCollapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-space">
      <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "About", simple_pages_about_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Contact", simple_pages_contact_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Products", products_path %></li>
    </ul>
<div  class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right navblock-margin" >
  <ul>
      <li class="sidebar">
        <%= form_with(url: products_path, method: "get", local: true, class: "navbar-form navbar-right") do |form| %>
          <%= form.text_field :q, id: "q", value: params[:q], type: "text", class: "form-control", placeholder: "search text" %>
          <%= submit_tag("Search", class: "btn btn-search") %>
        <% end %>
      </li>
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
      <li class="sidebar btn btn-search"><%= link_to("logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete)%></li>
        <% else %>
      <li class="sidebar btn btn-search"><%= link_to("login", new_user_session_path)%></li>
        <% end %>
  </ul>
</div><!--end nav div-->
  </div><!--end container-fluid-->
  </div><!--end navbar collapse-->
```

stylesheet:

```
h1 {
   margin-top: 4%;
 }
 nav ul li {
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: middle;
 }

nav .navbarCollapse ul li a {
  font-family: 'Shadows Into Light', cursive;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

nav .navbarCollapse ul li.sidebar a {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Copse', serif;
  color: #eea838;
}

nav .navbarCollapse ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #6f2d2e;
  color: #eea838;
  font-size: 26px;
}

nav .navbarCollapse ul li.sidebar a:hover {
  background-color: #6f2d2e;
    font-family: 'Copse', serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

body {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 33px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 18px;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #6f2d2e;
  font-family: 'Shadows Into Light', cursive;
}

.nav-space {
  margin-left: 12%;
}

.header-margin {
  margin: 0, 50px;
}

#q {
   color: black;
   border-radius: 1rem;
   font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
}

.navbar-text {
  font-family: 'Shadows Into Light', cursive;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 240%;
}

.btn-search {
  background-color: #85CB33;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Copse', serif;
}
.navblock-margin {
margin-right: 2%;
}
.btn-search:hover {
  background-color: #85CB33;
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-family: 'Copse', serif;
}   

a:hover {
  color: #75DBCD;
}
.icon-bar {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}
input {
border-color:#ccc;
border-width: 1px;
}
a:visited {
  color: black;
}
#notice {
  color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It feels like you haven't specified the size you aim to get of their related class `.sidebar`.

If you don't specify any size you'll get random results. I think you should set a limit to your zone.

```
.sidebar {width: 100px; height: 30px;}
```

Also, in you css, you need to claim you `body` before anything else.

Comment: The width probably shouldn't be in px, because then on large screens the buttons will be tiny -- use em or %.

Comment: .sidebar is a class I set trying to fix things to no avail. I should have removed it before posting to be clearer I suppose. No luck with that fix. Ruby on rails doesn't need you to include body, although it might have something to do with the embedded ruby code.

Comment: `em` or `%` => sure thing for real life sheets. I used px in my example as things were written in px in the css there